# API posts x-www-form-urlencoded data but fails on json

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a basic Mongo API.
During testing, I can easily post data with postman when it is `x-www-form-urlencoded` but when I use raw JSON, it is just blank.

I stored the body to see what was the difference and noticed that while using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` format there was data but when using JSON, my object was blank and doesn't post anything.

The data schema is as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Setup schema
var testSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    fieldone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    fieldtwo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    fieldthree: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    fieldfour: String,
    fieldfive: String,
    fieldsix: String
});

// Export model
var test= module.exports = mongoose.model('test', testSchema);
module.exports.get = function(callback, limit) {
test.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

The controller is as below:

```
// Controller.js
// Import model
Test= require('./Model');

// insert new test
// Handle create actions
exports.new = function(req, res) {
const {
    fieldone,
    fieldtwo,
    fieldthree,
    fieldfour,
    fieldfive,
    fieldsix
} = req.body
var test= new Test(req.body);
// console log for testing if the data shows
console.log(test)

// save and check for errors
    test.save(function(err) {
        // if (err)
        //     res.json(err);
        res.json({
            message: 'New test created!',
            data: test
        });
    });

};
```

Below is my api-routes

```
// api-routes.js
// Initialize express router
const router = require('express').Router();
// Set default API response
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        status: 'alls good',
        message: 'alls good',
    });
});
// Import controller
const testController = require('./Controller');
// routes
router.route('/test')
    .get(testController.index)
    .post(testController.new);

// Export API routes
module.exports = router;
```

Below is my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();

// Import routes
var apiRoutes = require("./api-routes");

var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

// mongo con
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongodojo', { useNewUrlParser: true 
});
var db = mongoose.connection;

// error check
if (!db)
    console.log("Error while connecting")
else
    console.log("connection successful")

 // Setup server port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Welcome'));
```

Is there anything in my code that could be causing this?

Comment: Can you post your `index.js` or `server.js`??

Comment: added the rest of my files to the post